# How to enable the vertical and horizontal scrollbars in DataGrip IDE?

Tags: mysql, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

I recently downloaded DataGrip for Windows and I noticed that there are no scrollbars for the console output. I have searched all over the settings but I cant finding anything that will let me add or enable the scrollbars for the result ouput. I have DataGrip 2016.3.3.

How can I enable this?

[image]

Comment: @moscas Sorry, but that link isn't working for me.

Comment: And this? https://pp.userapi.com/c636728/v636728435/681d5/3NhJiKxh9sA.jpg

Comment: @moscas Hmm I see it on yours but I dont have it on mine...added a screenshot to my post to show.

Comment: Are you sure that there IS INFORMATION to scroll?

Comment: Yes, for sure. I am able to scroll using the direction arrows on the keyboard

Comment: Can I ask you to record a screencast?

Comment: Is it still actual?